# How the index of pointwise stabilizer is 1 or 2 in $Aut(X)$?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, automorphism-group

Let $X = (V,E)$ be a connected trivalent graph, $e = (v_1,v_2)$ an edge of $X$. We define:

$A^{(0)}$ as the pointwise stabilizer in $Aut(X)$ of all vertices in $V_0=\{v_1, v_2\}$ where $Aut(X)$ is the automorphisms of $X$.

Then according to a theorem of Tutte, $Aut_e(X)$, the group of all those automorphisms of $X$ which stabilize the edge $e$, is a $2$-group. The proof states that, $A^{(0)}$ has index 1 or 2 in $Aut(X)$.

Index 1 means  $A^{(0)}= Aut(X)$, it is understandable when $Aut_e(X)=Aut(X)$, but when  index is 2?

How can we prove that?

Comment: If you fix an edge then either you fix both the ends, or you swap the ends.

Comment: @ancientmathematician you can not swap vertices because by definition $A^{(0)}$ is the point-wise stabilizer, all elements of  $A^{(0)}$ , fixes both the vertices.

Comment: But $\text{Aut}_e(X)$ can swap the end points, and that's all it can do except fix them both. So index 2 down to $A^{(0)}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes, you are correct, misses the idea of cosets.